# Implementing state machine pattern in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, state-machine

I am working on some 'call-control' application to be developed in wpf.
I want to implement state machine pattern in my C# code for following purpose:

there are various states as mentioned in following figure.

[image]
when call is in '**ringing**' state and I click on answer button, state goes into '**Talk**' and button gets **disabled**.
Please provide me useful **links/documents** that will help me. Is there any built in state class for implementing this?
Thanks in adv.

Comment: Have you done any research into existing solutions / samples already? Have you attempted any code design or implementation?

Comment: yes. I saw few questions on this site only. and also gone through msdn link: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-us?query=StateMachine+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VisualStateManager is the thing which design specifically to handle visual application states.

here's where you start with it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.visualstatemanager.aspx

and here's a good tutorial (doesn't require Blend):
http://windowsclient.net/wpf/wpf35/wpf-35sp1-toolkit-visual-state-manager-overview.aspx

you can do a lot of cool things including animated transitions between states etc.

For the actual implementation it's got little to do with WPF - I'd suggest looking at state pattern (ex. http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/38956-Very-Simple-StateMachine-Pattern-C and many others).

Comment: Thanks. I am going to try this now.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I think your question should be easily solvable with a little application of programming knowledge and thought. However, after a quick look on Google, I found a post on [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/GenericStateMachine.aspx) that introduces a very simple, generic state machine implementation in C#. This may help you to find what you need and implement a solution tailored to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

Tou can have a look at [WF4 state machine](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Windows-Workflow-f2c91fd7) workflow